# com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found

Tags: java, rest, ssl-certificate, xpages, lotus-notes

In our IBM Domino based application we are about to integrate with a system using REST API.

However, recently we came across a problem which seems very hard to solve.

When sending a request, we get the following exception

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=14, col=32: Error calling method 'initializeAuthProcess(string, string)' on java class 'ru.iteko.egrz.requestprocessors.EGRZAuthorization'
com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found
No trusted certificate found
```

The reason why it's so embarassing is because lack of documentation and any kind of a guide why all this happens.

So, there's a click action on a button like so

```
 <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var redirectUrl = 'https://oursystem.ru';
    var errorRedirectUrl = 'https://oursystem.ru/errorPage';

    var EGRZAuthObject = new ru.iteko.egrz.requestprocessors.EGRZAuthorization();

    EGRZAuthObject.initializeAuthProcess(redirectUrl, errorRedirectUrl);

    }]]></xp:this.action>
 </xp:eventHandler>
```

In an instance of EGRZAuthorization class there's the following method called

```
public static void initializeAuthProcess(String redirectUrl, String apiRedirectUrl) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
{
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String urlToGoTo = AuthURLs.ESIALoginURL(redirectUrl, apiRedirectUrl);
    System.out.println(urlToGoTo);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlToGoTo);
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    System.out.println("resp code " + response1.getStatusLine());
    response1.close();
}
```

The exception occurs where the request gets executed.

Stacktrace:

```
com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: No trusted certificate found
    com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:183)
    com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.b(g.java:43)
    com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:4)
    com.ibm.jsse2.aB.a(aB.java:211)
    com.ibm.jsse2.aB.a(aB.java:5)
    com.ibm.jsse2.aB.checkServerTrusted(aB.java:49)
    com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:166)
    com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:121)
    com.ibm.jsse2.D.r(D.java:223)
    com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:198)
    com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:649)
    com.ibm.jsse2.at.i(at.java:627)
    com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:689)
    com.ibm.jsse2.at.startHandshake(at.java:432)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    ru.iteko.egrz.requestprocessors.EGRZAuthorization.initializeAuthProcess(EGRZAuthorization.java:32)
```

Here's the smart bit. The `urlToGoTo` variable equals to  `http://lk.egrz-test.i-teco.ru/fws/api/esia/login?errorRedirectUrl=https://oursystem.ru/errorPage&redirectUrl=https://oursystem.ru`

And what it does is redirecting a user to an external resource for authorization.

To sum up here what it all looks like:

1. We send a GET request to the `urlToGoTo`
2. Then that service redirects us to a resource which uses HTTPS (if it matters)

But we can't even see it, cause get the exception above. The request isn't executed at all.

We have already installed the required certificate (external source, auth, HTTPS, where we get redirected in the end) and cross-certified it. But still with no luck.

I hope that there's any solution, please help. Personally, I have no idea why this happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cerificate of the REST service you are calling is signed with an unknown CA. The cert chain is broken, so it is correct to throw an error. You have two options: 1. get the correct certificates, or 2. disable the certification check in your http client.

Comment: Much more interested in the second option. How can I do that? Also,
provided that I have the entire chain, how do I add those to the server?

Comment: It seems that the import of certificates is only available on Windows machines
https://web.archive.org/web/20140315083722/http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588966

Comment: You can make a copy of the server's *cacert* file and do the steps descriped in your link on a windows machine (*ikeyman.exe* is also available in Notes Client). And then use the file on the server.

Comment: Much more interesting is the *first* option. The second option is radically insecure.

Comment: We have had a similar case. We found out that certificate had 2 minor issues:
a) the root certificate had a later validation date
b) addition certificate chain was missing for AAA certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the way to fix that is as follows:

```
sudo /*path to ikeycmd*/ -cert -add -db /*path to cacerts*/ -file /*path to ssl certificate*/ -format binary -trust enable -type jks
```

It might prompt for password. Default is `changeit`

Better to import the entire chain

Then execute command `res ser` in Domino Administrator.

Now it should work

Comment: but that means you have to import this certificate on every server that establish connections... meaning if you add more servers - you would have to repeat that. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You could access the site with certificate checking disabled. I strongly advise against it. It would be a barn door size security hole.  But if you have to, you could use the easyTrustManager as described here: https://wissel.net/blog/2007/08/ssl-in-domino-agents.html

```
    public class HttpsCommonFetcher { 

        /** Log object for this class. */ 
        private static final Log LOG = LogFactory. getLog(HttpsCommonFetcher. class); 

        public String getContentFromHTTP(String xRequest, String targetURL; String method) { 
                String result = null; 
                HttpMethod httpMethod = null; 

                // This implementation uses the HTTP Common client from the 
                // Apache jakarta Project. See: http://jakarta.apache.org/httpcomponents/index.html 
                // and http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/httpclient/sslguide.html 
                // We use the EasySSL Implementation to avoid SSL configuration stress 

                String hostwithoutSSL = this.targetURL.substring(8); 
                LOG.info(hostwithoutSSL); 

                // We use the simple SSL methods that doesn't compare with the keystore remove the 2 lines if you intend to config SSL 
                        Protocol myhttps = new Protocol("https", 
                                        new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443); 
                        Protocol. registerProtocol("https", myhttps); 

                HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient(); 

                // Here would be the optional Proxy code                 
                // httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(pHost, pPort); 
           if (method.qualsIgnoreCase( "POST" )) { 
                        // We only support get and post and if it is not POST it is GET 
                        PostMethod pm = new PostMethod( this . targetURL ); 
                        // Populate the body of the request 
                        RequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(xRequest); 
                        pm.setRequestEntity(entity); 
                        httpMethod = (HttpMethod) pm; 
                } else { 
                        httpMethod = new GetMethod( this . targetURL ); 
                } 
                // Make sure we follow eventual redirects 
                httpMethod.setFollowRedirects( true); 

                // Now we retrieve the stuff 
                try { 
                        int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(httpMethod); 
                        // Here we have the result already 
                        LOG.info(httpMethod.getStatusLine()); 
                        
                        if (statusCode == HttpStatus. SC_OK ) { 
                                // Directly read it into a String ... creates a warning in 
                                // HTTPClient but is what we would do anyway. 
                                result = httpMethod.getResponseBodyAsString(); 
                        } else { 
                                result = "<error>" + httpMethod.getStatusLine() + "</error>" ; 
                        } 

                } catch (HttpException e) { 
                        LOG.error(e); 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                        LOG.error(e); 
                } finally { 
                        httpMethod.releaseConnection(); 
                } 
                return result; 
        } 
}
```